# Google maps API on wordpress with KML files

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

*Quick preliminary note: I'm not a web developer, but am working on a proof-of-concept website while I shop around for grants to pay someone else to re-do my work properly, so hacky workarounds are fine. This won't ever be the public facing version of the site.*

The site is built in wordpress and needs to call the google maps api to show kml files for some pages. A sample page is here: http://35.189.56.28/index.php/project-details/?project=ERF101548. I used the code from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

Previously, I spent about three days fiddling to get this to work. I found that I needed to put half of the javascript inside the head tags (the script to call the KML file) and part in the body (the part to draw the map). It *was* working perfectly.

Today, without thinking I updated the theme the site uses and (of course) in doing that I overwrote my custom header.php. That means the working google maps API code is now lost. And I can't remember how I got it working in the end.

I have managed to get my php right in that it is putting the following into head:

```
<style>
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/erfmonitor/erf_kml/ERF101548.kml',
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
```

The script in the body is unchanged from what was working before, but for reference, it is:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB-zp5Xlxyc3BIUxoR7zejWG1z5WpnaLQ8&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Would someone be able to help me out with possible solutions? It seems the right javascript is there, but is not executing. This is the same problem I have last time, but I can't for the life of me remember how I fixed it.

Ta.

Comment: Tim try to set fixed height of the map something like `400px`. It is actually there but with height `0px`. Google maps requires fixed height. You try changing `#map {    height: 100%;  }` to `#map { height: 400px; }`

Comment: I gave that a shot (see the source for the sample page in OP), but it's still not working. I feel like the answer *was* something like this, though. I remember I played with async and defer for a long while and the solution was something really simple.

Comment: I don't know but in my developer console I see **Invalid property name** warning. Try to copy the word from here `height`, I did such a mistake maybe you wrote unicode character there. Also try to put `height: 400px !important`

Comment: Actually I don't know how you succeed to do it but it is written " height" instead of "height" there is one empty space there :))

Comment: Weirdly, I couldn't get the definition for height inside the style tags to work (and still can't) but It worked when I gave the div the style property in the tag itself. 

`<div id="map" style="height: 400px;">&nbsp;</div>`.

Ah well. It works now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are very welcome, good luck in your deeds :)